# How to use transform {"type": "flatten"}, and get data buckets in vega-lite

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization, vega, vega-lite

I am trying to create a visualize vega-lite/v2.json with transform ("type": "flatten").
but it's not working.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fazPL.png)

code:

```
{
    $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json
    data: {
        url: {
        index: elk_map_statistic-*
        body: {
            size: 0,
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {"range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                                "gte": "now-6m",
                                "lt": "now"
                        }
                    }                   
                ]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_host": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "DestBuilding.keyword",
                        "size": 20000
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                        "DestRoom" : {
                            "terms" : {
                                "field" : "DestRoom.keyword",
                                "size" : 500
                            }
                        },
                        "avg" : { "avg" : { "field" : "avg" } },
                        "types_count" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "count" } }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

        }
        format: {property: "aggregations.group_by_host.buckets"}
    },


    "transform": [
        {
        "type": "flatten",
        "fields": ["brand.buckets"],
        "as": ["val"]
        }
    ],

    mark: rect


    "encoding": {

        "x": {"field": "val.key", "type": "ordinal"},
        "y": {"field": "key", "type": "ordinal"}
    },

}
```

How to use ("type": "flatten"), if I want to get data in buckets?

I found an example for vega:https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1155

Comment: Hi! Could you please directly paste your data in text format? So the community will help you easier.

Comment: Is there any reason you're required to use vega-lite v2? The flatten transform was [added to vega-lite in version 3.0](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/releases/tag/v3.0.0), so your issue might be that your vega-lite version is too old.